# Best way to watch a large number of directories?

Tags: java, linux

I have written a [music player in Java/JavaFX](http://hypnosplayer.org/) that (among other things) watches the user's music library folder for any changes and updates the program's library data if there is a change on the filesystem.

I accomplish this with a [SimpleFileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) and a [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html). The `SimpleFileVisitor` recurively walks through the target folder heirarchy, and registers each folder with the `WatchService`. Full code below.

On my Ubuntu 18.04, if I try to register a number of folders that each have a lot of subfolders in this way, I eventually get the error `java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify watches reached`.

It turns out that the Linux kernel limits the number of inotify watches that can be done in the file `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`.  The common default is 8192. This limit is for every program run by the user, and there are other popular programs which use a lot, like DropBox.

My library potentially wants a lot as well. For the sort of user who might use this program, 1000 - 25000 folders that want to be watched is a reasonable estimate. I would expect most users to fall in the 2000 - 5000 range.

A solution is to notify the users of the error and tell them to increase the `max_user_watches` number in the kernel, which can be done, but I don't like putting that burden on the user if it can be avoided.

Is there another good way to be notified of changes in a folder hierarchy in java without overloading the inotify number on Linux?

My full watcher code can be found here, starting on line 545: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/blob/55da2819a3862d5c2a14797a9ce45e9171f7076e/src/net/joshuad/hypnos/Library.java#L545

You can also see the main walker code here:

```
private void watcherRegisterAll ( final Path start ) {
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree( 
            start, 
            EnumSet.of( FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS ), 
            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            new SimpleFileVisitor <Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory ( Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
                    WatchKey key = dir.register( 
                        watcher, 
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, 
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY 
                    );

                    keys.put( key, dir );
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            }
        );

    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Unable to watch directory for changes: " + start.toString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: On some systems the watch service may fall back internally to a polling approach if not supported nativelly. Yes, its better and less heavy to use WatchService, but in your case maybe give a try for a self-made polling (+pro it will be multi-platform out-of-the-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one, and `inotify` is the most performant way to do this. If you run into this issue, you could just prompt the user to increase limit on their behalf to provide a better user experience (you have to perform a privilege escalation by asking for password for this).

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know if a similar limitation exists in windows? I haven't run into it yet, but it may be out there above my numbers.

Comment: Not familiar with Windows limitations unfortunately.